# Django rest framework : extend user model for customer - one to one field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-users, django-serializer

I have a customer model in Bcustomer app that extends the django User model, So I will save the basic details such as name in User table and the remaining data (city, etc) in customer table.

When I call the below code through API, it shows the following error. But data is saving in the tables. I also want to implement the get and put calls for this api.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `city` on serializer `CustomerSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'city'.
```

my Bcustomer/models.py

```
class BCustomer(models.Model):

    customer = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, blank=True )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer_creator')
    # more fields to go

    def __str__(self):
        # return str(self.name) (This should print first and last name in User model)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'bcustomer'
```

my Bcustomer/serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from models import BCustomer


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    city = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name', 'email','city')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        userModel = get_user_model()
        email = validated_data.pop('email', None)
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name', None)
        city = validated_data.pop('city', None)

        request = self.context.get('request')
        creator = request.user

        user = userModel.objects.create(
            first_name=first_name,
            email=email,
            # etc ...
        )

        customer = BCustomer.objects.create(
            customer=user,
            city=city,  
            user=creator
            # etc ...
        )

        return user

my Bcustomer/views.py

class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    customer_photo_thumb = BCustomer.get_thumbnail_url
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = BCustomer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

my Bcustomer/urls.py

```
router.register(r'customer', views.CustomerViewSet, 'customers')
```

POST request format

```
{
  "first_name":"Jsanefvf dss",
  "city":"My City",
  "email":"myemail@gmail.com",
  #more fields
}
```

I also need to implement put and get for this api. Now data is saving in both tables but shows the error.

Comment: If the `CustomerSerializer` is supposed to serialize `BCustomer` ,  then why is the model set to `get_user_model`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it complains.

Validation goes well, so does the creation *but* once it's created, the view will deserialize the result and return it to the client.

This is the point where it goes south. Serializer is configured to think that `city` is a field of the default user while it actually is part of `BCustomer`. In order to work this around, you should set the `source` argument to the `city` field. You might need to update the serializer's `create`/`update` to reflect that change, not sure about that one.